# how to use a switch case for onDraw method?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, ondraw

I'm trying to use a switch case in an `onDraw` method so it changes what to draw when a button is pressed. I know the button works and the variable "b1" is being changed, but the `onDraw` doesn't change what to draw. I've tried using a .invalidate() in different parts of the code and doesn't change anything. the `onDraw` will only use the case that it initially loads when the program is run. I've even tried putting an update() method inside the `onDraw()` method to change the value of "b1" and it doesn't work.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    update();

    switch (b1){
        case 0:
            canvas.drawBitmap(offtank, 15, 550, null);
            break;
        case 1:
            for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
                sprite.onDraw(canvas);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(ontank, 15, 550, null);
            break;
    }
}
```

This is probably something simple, but I'm a noob and I'm totally stumped and can't find anything about this anywhere. Also, I've tried using an if statement instead of switch case and still the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in onDraw() and see 1)whether it gets called 2) variable b1 has the value you expected

Comment: What variable type is `b1` and what are it's possible values?

Comment: Why the last parameter of canvas.drawBitmap is null?. I think it should be a Paint object

Comment: If sprites is empty, you will get the result you describe.  gutiory, please read the documentation for drawBitmap.  null is fine, and it wouldn't have anything to do with the OPs question even it wasn't.  null just means draw the bitmap using it's raw pixels. [EDIT] ah, I see onTank and offTank.  OK, so try what Krishnabhadra suggests.

Comment: "b1" is an int variable. The sprites work, they draw what they're supposed to, it just doesn't switch which bitmap to draw when i press the button that changes the value of "b1".

Comment: ok i figured out that all my variables inside the onClick button and the method that passes variables back to the GameView class, are just being reset to their initial value for no reason everytime the program is done with that class and returns to the GameView class that the above code i included is in. why do the varaibles reset?

Comment: well its actually only the variables that are changed with the onClick button, but why do they reset? is there a way to make them not reset? i even tried using a final int outside of the onclick button to store the variable inside the onclick button, but that also resets when the program moves back to the other class. i'm using the breakpoint debug thing to see this. but now that i narrowed the problem, i still can't find anything on google about this problem, plz help!!